# How do we use articles with the "chef", in French? Which is correct "Vous êtes le/un chef"?

Tags: articles

Which sentences are correct?

1. Vous êtes le chef.
2. Vous êtes un chef.
3. Vous êtes chef.

And if they correct in some context, what do they mean?

Comment: 1& 2 are both correct but see difference between definite (le) and indefinite (un) articles. You have to use an article and 3 is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les sens sont différents.

**Vous êtes le chef.** = C'est vous le responsable, c'est vous qui décidez.

**Vous êtes un chef.** = Forme de reconnaissance: Vous êtes un expert, le meilleur, ...

**Vous êtes chef.** = expression plutôt incorrecte, **sauf** sous les formes:

- chef vu comme un grade, ou une profession (chef de cuisine), comme on dirait: *vous êtes colonel, vous êtes docteur.*
- extension implicite: *chef de l'équipe*, comme *directeur (de l'établissement)*.

Comment: Can't "le chef" also mean "the cook"?

Comment: @Roman . Oui, Le chef de cuisine, dans un restaurant. Par extension, "vous êtes un chef" pour une personne, pour la féliciter de son excellente cuisine.

Comment: Mais avec des professions, les articles ne s'utilisent pas?

Comment: @BenKnoble , pour les professions: on peut avec ou sans.

Comment: Merci--nous avons appris que l'on doit éviter les articles.